# How can I make 2 columns in a row s in visual composer backend, programmatically?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, visual-composer

How can I make 2 columns in a row s in visual composer back-end, programmatically. I have searched lot but unable to find any solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance. please check the screenshot.

http://screencast.com/t/nei41uN1mzyS

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what have you tried. Following code may be help.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[vc_row][vc_column width="1/2"][/vc_column][vc_column width="1/2"][/vc_column][/vc_row]' ) ?>
```